# Check if user is in a group on the main site FROM a subsite of a network (WP Multisite)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using Woocommerce + the groups plugin on my main site to promote users to a 'Premium' group upon purchasing items which works great.

If a user on the main site then browses to the second site within my network, I can no longer check to see if they're within the 'Premium' group.

On my main site, I can use this code:

```
<?php 
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $group = Groups_Group::read_by_name( 'Premium' );
    if ( Groups_User_Group::read( $user_id, $group->group_id ) ) { 
?>

    Premium content here!

<?php } ?>
```

But this does not work on the subsite. Is there anyway I can check to see if the user is in a group on my main site FROM a subsite?

Comment: Are you using multisite or just sites on the same server?

Comment: Last question as not sure I can help (not familiar with multisite), but when your clients leave the one site and goes onto another are they logged in still or do they have to re-authenticate? (do these other sites have a log in are/are they also woocommerce sites?)

Comment: I'm not that familiar with multisite as well but yes, they are still logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to achieve this using the following code:

```
<?php

    $blog_id = 1; //set the blog id to the main site id 

    switch_to_blog( $blog_id );

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $group = Groups_Group::read_by_name( 'Premium' );
    if ( Groups_User_Group::read( $user_id, $group->group_id ) ) { 
        echo 'PREMIUM!!';
    } else {
        echo 'Not premium';
    }

    restore_current_blog();

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably not a definitive answer but this should lead to it at least.

Your current code is using a wordpress function to get the users id. This should work across the board and is therefore fine. The next variabe/method uses the class from the groups plugin which I presume is just not being pulled on the subsite.

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$group = Groups_Group::read_by_name( 'Premium' );
Groups_User_Group::read( $user_id, $group->group_id )
```

From the look of the class files

```
$group = Groups_Group::read_by_name( 'Premium' );
```

This line simply does the method below

```
public static function read_by_name( $name ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $result = false;
    $group_table = _groups_get_tablename( 'group' );
    $group = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT * FROM $group_table WHERE name = %s",
        $name
    ) );
    if ( isset( $group->group_id ) ) {
        $result = $group;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

The next line

```
Groups_User_Group::read( $user_id, $group->group_id )
```

Does this method

```
public static function read( $user_id, $group_id ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $result = false;

    $user_group_table = _groups_get_tablename( 'user_group' );
    $user_group = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT * FROM $user_group_table WHERE user_id = %d AND group_id = %d",
        Groups_Utility::id( $user_id ),
        Groups_Utility::id( $group_id )
    ) );
    if ( $user_group !== null ) {
        $result = $user_group;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

So all you are doing is pretty simple calls to the database. The issue being that due to the use of multisite there will be discrepancies with the table prefixes etc.

According to this part of the codex

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Multi-Site_Variables

You can access other sites on the network much in the same way you can access the current site using `$wpdb` as a global variable. Therefore once you have ascertained the correct names of your tables, you should be able to modify these methods into simple functions that do the necessary work.

The first method doesn't even need to be used

```
$group = Groups_Group::read_by_name( 'Premium' );
```

As `$group` simply equals the id shown in the dashboard

[image: woocommerce dashboard]

Therefore the line can be coded statically ie

```
$group = 2;
```

The second method is purely checking if there is an entry of `user_id` 2 for example and `group_id` 2 say, in the group_users_group table. Here we have user 2 with both registered and premium group privileges. Shown here.

[image: group_user_group woocommerce]

Therefore user 2 (again id can be seen in the dashboard in the users section) will qualify.

I hope this helps.